# rename column names as null in R

Tags: r

Is there a way to rename the column name to NULL in R
FOr example

```
head(iris)
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

Expected output (So the first column name should be empty)

```
head(iris)
               Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

Answer (score 2):

We cannot rename as `NULL`, but can be blank (`""`)

```
names(iris)[1] <- ""
```

-output

```
 head(iris)
      Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1 5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2 4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3 4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4 4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5 5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6 5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

---

If we want to `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
iris %>% 
    rename_with(~ sQuote("", FALSE), .cols = 1) %>% 
    head
   '' Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1 5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2 4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3 4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4 4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5 5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6 5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this using pipe operator (%>%)